# Reading a whole string column from SQL Table as string array.

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to know whether it is possible to read an SQL Table string column, and assign it as string array. If yes, is there any procedure of how to do that ?. I have following code:

```
 using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Varenr, Navn, Stkpris FROM KreditNotaTable WHERE Varenr = @varenr", con))
                {
                    cm.Parameters.Clear();
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varenr", varenr);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string navn = reader["Navn"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But this example only returns a string from a specific row. I want all contents from the "Navn" column as string array.

Comment: How do the contents from that column look like? It really depends on that.

Comment: It's a name column. Only surnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split one row / column into a `string[]`, use `String.Split` and use the correct delimiter:

```
string[] navn = ((string)reader["Navn"])
                .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

In this case I used `Environment.NewLine` which is a line break (`\r\n`) on Windows.

If you want all rows / 1 column into the `string[]`, try this. You can't use `string[]` immediately, since you don't have the count of the rows.

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    s.Add((string)reader["Navn"]);
}

string[] arr = s.ToArray();
```